# How to create an index with JPA/hibernate and use fields from MappedSuperClass together with fields from concrete entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the `@MappedSuperClass` (simplified example):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MySuperClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date creationDate;

    // ...
}
```

and a concrete `Entity` (simplified example):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity extends MySuperClass {
    @Index(name = "IDX_MYINDEX")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MyType type;

    @Index(name = "IDX_MYINDEX")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MyResult status;

    // ...
}
```

Now I need an index including the columns `MySuperClass.creationDate`, `MyEntity.status` and `MyEntity.type`.

If I add `@Index(name = "IDX_MYINDEX")` to `MySuperClass.creationDate` hibernate adds an index of `creationDate` to every Entity inherited from `MySuperClass`.

I tried `@AttributeOverride` but it is not capable for indexes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you are using `JPA 2.1` then you can use class annotation `@Table` with its attribute indexes

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "IDX_MYIDX1", columnList = "id,name,surname") })
```

Please note that as documentation says

> These are only used if table generation is in effect.  Defaults to no
>   additional indexes.

`columnlist`, as shown above, accepts column names list as a comma-delimited list.

If you don't use JPA 2.1 you can just use old `Hibernate`s `@Index` annotation (note this is already deprecated). There's attribute `columnNames` where you can pass array of column names no matter above which field it is declared.

```
@Index(name = "IDX_MYIDX1", columnNames = { "id", "name", "surname"})
```

Answer (score 5):

Use @Index annotation and use the parameter "columnList" to set which columns should be used to make your index. That list should be made of a comma-separated list of values of the column names.

Important: Don't forget to add the column name property (via Column annotation) to all properties that make this index, otherwise you'll get an error when starting up your container.

Comment: I have tried adding Column annotation on the field with column name property, but still I get error when starting up container that the Key value is too long. Can you please help

Comment: @emphywork I think you will need to shorten the length of your fields that you are using in your index, this can be specified with the `@Column(length=..)` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure list column names that you've given in @Column's name attribute not fields' names.

Also enabling ddl-auto to update will create all the indexes.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWER_OPTION", indexes = {@Index(name="SEC_INDEX",columnList = "ID,SEQUENCE,QUESTION_ID,OPTION_TITLE")})
public class AnswerOptionEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "SEQUENCE")
private Long sequence;

@Column(name = "OPTION_TITLE")
private String optionTitle;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private QuestionEntity questionEntity;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "answerOptionEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
private List<ResultEntity> resultEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
@Table(name = "table_name",indexes = [Index(name = "name_of_index", columnList = "liste of fields separated by ',' ")])
```