# How to add indexes in hibernate Entity class? How to define index for JSON fields in hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am using PostgreSQL with Hibernate. I have added handling to persist JSON data for column in hibernate entity class. I want to define indexes for some of the JSON fields in that particular column. Please give me some suggetions. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If your hibernate version support JPA2.1, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24943436/6413377).